# installing pdfminer error, permission denied

Tags: python

I am trying to install pdfminer.
I get this error when using the command
    %python setup.py install

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pyPdf':
Permission denied
```

So i tried:

```
python2.4 setup.py install --home=$HOME/lib/python2.4
```

Now when i try
    pdf2txt.py -o output.html samples/simple1.pdf
I get another error:

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFDocument, PDFParser
ImportError: No module named pdfminer.pdfparser
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Obviously running the installation as normal user without root permissions since you are trying to install your stuff in /usr/local. Using sudo is your friend.

Comment: As said, it looks like you need admin rights to install this. Try executing this as root user. (Refer to your distribution's doc if you do not know how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install in the default location in `/usr/local` use sudo:

```
sudo python2.4 setup.py install
```

If you do not have root permissions, you can specify a custom location:

```
python2.4 setup.py install --home=$HOME/lib/python2.4
```

However, you need to ensure that location is on your python path:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/lib/python2.4:$PYTHONPATH
```

You can put this in your bash profile to ensure it is always added automatically. You can also add to the python path from within python:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/lib/python2.4')
```

Another alternative is to use a virtualenv. If virtualenv is not installed you will need root permissions to install it, but then you can put your virtualenvs wherever you want.